# SQL Server 2012 backward compatibility for backups with 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have a number of clients with SQL Server 2008 and that's what I have here on my server too. I use backup files to send databases back and forth between clients and at my office.

I have read that when you create a backup from SQL Server 2012 there is no way to restore it onto a 2008 instance. I assumed that the compatibility level would take care of this problem, but it doesn't. Therefore, I am at a loss as to how to upgrade. Other than upgrade all my clients all at once, which is impossible, I can think of no clean way to do this.

I have the need to send a database to a client as well as receive a database from a client. This is my first version upgrade on SQL Server, so I'm new to this problem. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Can you link to where you have read this, so we can have more context?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question; you may get better answers at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Here's where I read it:
http://sqlserverlearner.com/tag/database-restore-from-sql-server-2012-to-sql-server-2008

Comment: I don't believe this is something new with SQL Server 2012. Generally, once you upgrade SQL Server you are unable to restore a database to an earlier version of SQL Server even if you maintained the same db compatibility on the new SQL Server instance. I would probably suggest installing 2012 as a new named instance and keep the 2008 instance active as well. Keep track of which clients are on 2012 and which are on 2008 and use the correct instance for each client.

Comment: As a riff off of the suggestion of @TimLentine, do the upgrade yourself on your 2012 instance and then pass that database back and forth. That way, you can mitigate any upgrade issues before giving the db to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade the database one way (from SQL Server 2008 (or 2008 R2) to SQL Server 2012 and organize your upgrade to align to this direction.

You can also keep multiple server versions for the duration of the upgrade.